# What is the difference between char and unsigned char?

Tags: c, char, unsigned-char

**(Edited change C/C++ to C)**

Please help me to find out a clean clarification on `char` and `unsigned char` in C. Specially when we transfer data between embedded devices and general PCs (The difference between buffer of `unsigned char` and plain `char`).

Comment: There's no such thing as C/C++. You either use C or C++, but not both. Choose exactly one of the languages which you want to ask about. In C, the difference is in signedness. `char` may be signed or unsigned in an implementation-defined manner, whereas `unsigned char` is, obviously, always unsigned.

Comment: Can I know the difference and effects of char and unsigned char types during an encoding or decoding operation. ?

Comment: @user3447428 While they are indeed different languages and it does indeed not make sense to ask how something works in "C/C++", both languages happen to behave in exactly the same manner when it comes to `char`...

Comment: @user3458841 What is an "encoding or decoding operation"? That can mean anything.

Comment: @Lundin And it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're asking about two different languages but, in this respect, the answer is (more or less) the same for both. You really should decide which language you're using though.

Differences:

- they are distinct types
- it's implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned

Similarities:

- they are both integer types
- they are the same size (one byte, at least 8 bits)

If you're simply using them to transfer raw byte values, with no arithmetic, then there's no practical difference.

Comment: If I consider about 'C' language Can I know the difference and effects of char and unsigned char types during an encoding or decoding operations. ?

Comment: The only real difference is that `unsigned char` is not definitely signed, and `char` may or may not be signed. (It is _implementation defined_ whether `char` is signed or unsigned, which means that it can be either, completely at the whim of your compiler writer, but the compiler must document which one it is.) When working with raw data, you should explicitly use `unsigned char`. When working with meaningful data, you should choose a signed type or an unsigned type depending on the meaning of your data. Use plain `char` if the signedness of the data is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

The type char is special. It is not an unsigned char or a signed char. These are three distinct types (while int and signed int are the same types). A char might have a signed or unsigned representation.

From 3.9.1 Fundamental types

> Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types. A
>   char, a signed char, and an unsigned char occupy the same amount of
>   storage and have the same alignment requirements (3.11); that is, they
>   have the same object representation.

Comment: Hi Dieter, Is there any consideration for _char_ and _unsigned char_ during an encode or decode operation which is done by hardware level (in device driver development) ?

Comment: Thanks, I clarified well.