# C++ strings vs vector<char>

Tags: c++, string, vector

It's known to everyone of us that we should prefer `string` class in `C++` for all string applications due to the many special functions they perform & their ability to grow & reduce dynamically. What `string` is for `characters`, `vector` is for other data types & classes because it shows great performance.

However is there any situation where we would need to prefer `vector<char>` (which I see seldom) over `string` ?

Comment: When handling binary data?

Comment: not at all @NathanOliver

Comment: could you please elaborate @AlejandroDíaz

Comment: @CppNITR If you're reading a binary file you'd want to store that in a `std::vector<char>`, think of any file that isn't text(an executable file for example)

Comment: These are interchangeable, std::string just offers additional functionality.

Comment: I want to see `byte` and not `char` for the vector personally and let the defines handle signed or unsigned behind the scenes.

Comment: `vector` is a container, `string` is a string.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Then it is a vector<unsigned char>, signed char, unsigned char and char are three distinct types

Comment: Well aware - but what char type should we be storing binary data in when it is "bytes"?  I prefer byte :)

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz: if it is a byte array would not you use unsigned char instead of char?

Comment: @quser I don't have a reason to use one over the other(I was actually just googling it)

Comment: @quser According to this answer there should be no practical difference if you're transporting raw bytes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629728/what-is-the-difference-between-char-and-unsigned-char

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz That's a C answer, and doesn't necessarily apply to C++.

Comment: @zenith I can't find anything else though, and I'm afraid of asking as it could be a duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `vector<char>` only if I explicitly intent to store an array of char values, which is not a string. E.g. if for some reason I'd collect all the characters used somewhere in a specific text, the result might be a `vector<char>`.

To be clear: it is all about expressing the intent.

Comment: To be clear: it is about expressing intent.

Comment: Good comment. Belongs in the answer. I recommend an edit to the answer to beat that point home.

Comment: You can do the same things with string too coz string too has push_back, pop_back, etc type functions which vector uses

Comment: @cdonat, i guess the doubt raised by CppNITR is valid, provide a better justification atleast

Comment: @CppNITR Yes, but this is a readability issue as much as anything else. A reader of your code sees `string`, they are going to expect certain things to be true, not the least of which is the string variable contains readable, and probably printable, text. A `vector` contains. What it contains varies based on the template argument and the interpretation of the content is wider in scope.

Comment: Sure a string can be used for that as well. Basically everything could ever be done with std::string as well as with std::vector<char>. I have edited my answer, as suggested by @user4581301, to make clear, that it is about the intent. Is the data used as something text-like, or as a collection of otherwise not connected char-objects?

Comment: yeah but for byte more natural for me is unsigned char e.g. range 0-255

Comment: @quser In my example I do store independent character values in the vector, not just bytes. Since I said, it is about expressing the intent, we here have an ordered collection of otherwise unrelated characters. It is not anything text-like, and therefore no `std::string`, and it is actually characters, not just bytes, and therefore no `std::vector<unsigned char>` or the like.

Answer (score 1):

To put it briefly: if you're storing text, then `string`, otherwise `vector<char>`.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating with a good example

Comment: if it is a byte array would not you use unsigned char instead of char?

Comment: @quser In that case I would prefer a `vector<byte>` with `using byte = char;` to make it clear it's storing raw binary data and not characters. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8386615/3425536) why `char` instead of `unsigned char`.

Comment: Also the C++ standard library itself uses `char`, not `unsigned char`, for binary I/O, e.g. [`ostream::write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/). So you avoid a lot of nasty casts with `using byte = char`.

Comment: @zenith: you mean there is issue if I used unsigned char instead?

Comment: @quser Yes, the issue that you need to do the casting when doing binary I/O with the C++ standard library.

Comment: @zenith: Why? does C++ I/O require char pointers as arguments? honestly I didn't really get the answer you linked to

Comment: Yes. See the documentation on e.g. the `istream`/`ostream` binary read/write functions. They accept char pointers.