# char * vs unsigned char* what is the difference?

Tags: c, linux, char, unsigned

In Linux with c , I didn't understant what is the diffrence between `char*` and `unsigned char*` When I reading/writing binary buffer ?

When I must not using `char*` and need to use `unsigned char*`?

Comment: the unsigned won't have negative numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between char and unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629728/what-is-the-difference-between-char-and-unsigned-char)

Comment: It's implementation defined if `char` is signed or unsigned. `unsigned char` is always unsigned.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  I edit the post, I taking when I reading /writing binary buffer with C

Comment: For example, if you need to compare the bytes and consider 0xff greater than 0x01, then you should use `unsigned char *`. But if you consider 0xff is lesser than 0x01, you should use `signed char *`.

Answer (score 3):

First recall C has `unsigned char`, `signed char` and `char`: 3 distinct types.  `char` has the same range as either  `unsigned char` or `signed char`.

[Edit]

OP added "When I reading/writing binary buffer" so the far below sections (my original post) deals with "what is the difference between `char*` and `unsigned char*`" with a sample case without that r/w concern. Within this section ....

Reading/writing binary  via `<stdio.h>` can be done with any I/O function although it is more common to to use `fread()/fwite()`.

For byte orientated data, all I/O functions behave as if

> The byte input functions read characters from the stream as if by successive
> calls to the `fgetc` function.  C17dr § 7.21.3 11
> The byte output functions write characters to the stream as if by successive
> calls to the `fputc` function. § 7.21.3 12

So let us look at those two.

> ... the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` ... § 7.21.7.1 2
> The `fputc` function writes the character specified by c (converted to an `unsigned char`) § 7.21.7.3 2

Thus all I/O at the lowest level is best thought of as reading/writing `unsigned char`.

Now to directly address

> When I must not using `char*` and need to use `unsigned char*`? (OP)

With writing, pointers such as `char*`, `unsigned char*` or others can be used at OP level code, yet the underlying output function accesses data via  `unsigned char *`.  This has no impact on OP's execution of the write other than if `char` was encoded as ones' complement/sign magnitude - a trap code would not get detected.

Likewise with reading, the underlying input function saves data via `unsigned char *` and no traps occur.   A single byte read via `int fgetc()` would report values in the `unsigned char` range even if `char` is *signed*.

The importance of using `unsigned char*` vs. `char*` in reading/writing binary buffer comes not so much in the I/O call itself (it all `unsigned char *` access), but in the setting up of data prior to writing and the interpretation of data after reading - see `memcmp()` below.

---

---

> When I must not using `char*` and need to use `unsigned char*`?

A good example is with string related code.

Although functions in `<string.h>` use `char*` in function parameters, the implementations performs as if `char` was `unsigned char`, even when `char` is *signed*.

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).  C17dr § 7.24.1 3

So even if `char` is a *signed* `char`, functions like `int strcmp(char *a, char *b)` perform as if `int strcmp(unsigned char *a, unsigned char *b)`.

1. This makes a difference when string differ by a *signed* `char c` and `char d` with values of different signs.
   E.g. Assume `c < 0, d > 0`

   // Accessed via `char *` and `char` is signed
   c < d is true
   // Accessed via `unsigned char *`
   c > d is false

This results in a different sign from the `strcmp()` return and so affects sorting strings.

```
// Incorrect code when `char` is signed.
int strcmp(const char *a, const char *b) {
  while (*a == *b && *a) { a++; b++; }
  return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}

// Correct code when `char` is signed or unsigned, 2's complement or not
int strcmp(const char *a, const char *b) {
  const char *ua = a;
  const char *ub = b;
  while (*ua == *ub && *ua) { ua++; ub++; }
  return (*ua > *ub) - (*ua < *ub);
}
```

[Edit]

The like-wise applies to binary data read and compared with `memcmp()`.

2. In old C implementations that did not use 2's complement, there could be 2 zeros: +0 and -0 (or trap).

+0 ended a string when properly view as a `unsigned char`.  -0 is not a *null character* to terminate a string, even though as a *signed* `char` it has a value of zero.

```
// Incorrect code when `char` is signed and not 2's complement.
// Conversion to `unsigned char` done too late.
int strcmp(const char *a, const char *b) {
  while ((unsigned char)*a == (unsigned char)*b && (unsigned char)*a) { a++; b++; }
  return ((unsigned char)*a > (unsigned char)*b) - ((unsigned char)*a < (unsigned char)*b);
}
```

Comment: Huh? Q: "I didn't understand the difference...", A: "1) This makes a difference when..." There seems to be almost an exact correlation.